# Passing variable to another view (using Utility template)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, view

Okay, so I'm obviously a newbie, but I need some help passing a variable to another view. I'm using the Utility Template in Xcode.

I think I have everything linking properly (including the proper header files and whatnot). Just don't know the proper syntax. Here's what I'm trying:

```
NSDate *time =[flipsideViewController.datePicker date];
```

If I run this in RootViewController.toggleView it works fine.

Any would would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You've showed us what works. What doesn't work? It's not clear from what you've written what you're trying to do.

Comment: @jlehr: when I say it works fine in the RootViewController, I mean I can set the variable, but how would I then access that from the mainView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are different ways to pass one variable to another view as:

1) Crate a global variable in appDelegateClass:

1. In appDelegate.h crate a vriable as NSString *str with property
2. In appDelegate.m syntheses it.
3. In View1 set this variable as:

   yourAppDelegate *appdelegate= [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

appdelegate.str= @"some string";

1. In view2 again crate a same object and retrieve value.
   NSString *myStr= appdelegate.str;

The another way is to define property in view2 and access it from View one.